# Does java support nested methods?

Tags: java

Are nested methods possible in Java? This is the Spring application I have found with nested methods. Please explain.

```
@Bean
MessageService mockMessageService() {
    return new MessageService() {
        public String getMessage() {
          return "Hello World!";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: i was confused with this syntax in java. please help friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Nested methods are not possible.

Your example does not show nested methods.

Your example returns an anonymous class declared and implemented inline!

`mockMessageService` is the method

`new MessageService(){ ... }` is the anonymous class implementing the MessageService interface

`getMessage` is just a method in that anonymous class to implement the MessageService interface correctly